# How can I detect a click on the edge of a polygon with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

SITUATION:
I have a Leaflet map (with Leaflet.draw). On this map are various geometries (points, lines, polygons), added as geoJson (using L.geoJson). Each geometry has a click handler.

PROBLEM:
When someone clicks INSIDE a polygon, the click event is fired.

SOLUTION:
I only want the click event fired when the polygon edge (the closed polyline) is clicked. A workaround would be to detect the distance of the click to the edge.

I can't find a documented solution for this. Would be grateful for help.

Comment: Maybe usefull : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I could think of is to create an additional polyline with the same coordinates and put it on top of the polygon, and make the polygon unclickable. That would require adding a bit of logic for GeoJSON feature creation with `onEachFeature`.

Leaflet's polygons (and polylines) are made of a single SVG element, I'm not sure if it's possible to detect clicks on the outer edges without doing some Javascript math or similar, the `onclick` event simply attaches to the whole element.

```
var polyoverlay = new L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var edgeoverlay = new L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

var geojsonobj = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-87.027648, 20.820875 ], [-87.027648, 21.320875 ], [-86.527648, 21.320875 ], [-86.527648, 20.820875 ], [-87.027648, 20.820875 ] ] ] } } ] };

var poly = L.geoJson(geojsonobj, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
    // latitude/longitude to longitude/latitude coordinates
    var lonlats = [];
    feature.geometry.coordinates[0].forEach(function(f){
      lonlats.push([f[1], f[0]]);
    });

    // add polyline to map
    var polyline = L.polyline(lonlats,{
        color: 'black'
      }).bindPopup('hello').addTo(edgeoverlay);

    // add polygon to map        
    var polygon = L.polygon(lonlats,{
        color: 'blue',
        clickable: false
      }).addTo(polyoverlay);
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/w5Ta96X9TVOqHpHw1jZQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the polygon is a single SVG element. Your answer and @iH8's answer has given me a basic idea how I could handle this. I should have a PolyLine as the graphical presentation of the Polygon, and when clicked I could hide the PolyLine and present the actual Polygon for editing. Thanks!

Comment: I have implemented this (also using @iH8's code), and it works like a charm. Thanks again for this answer!

Answer (score 2):

Started this answer while overlooking @chrki's answer, mine is similar but turned out a bit differently, uses less logic and less layers. So i thought i'de throw it in here for good measure.

As said there is no way in Leaflet to detect an edgeclick. Once you attach a event to a feature, it responds on the entire element. What you could do is double draw the feature, put a polyline on the top of the polygon generated by the geojson layer and attach the listener to the polyline instead of the polygon.

```
// Create geojson layer w/o adding data
var geojson = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
    // Don't draw the stroke
    style: function () {
        return {
            stroke: false
        }
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // Check if layer is a polygon
        if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
            // Fetch coordinates from polygon
            var latLngs = layer.getLatLngs();
            // Push first coordinate to complete line
            latLngs.push(latLngs[0]);
            // Create polyline using coordinates
            var polyline = new L.Polyline(latLngs);
            // Add click listener
            polyline.on('click', function () {
                alert('Polyline clicked!');
            });
            // Add polyline to featuregroup
            polyline.addTo(featureGroup);
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);

// Create featuregroup, add it to the map
var featureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);

// Test 
geojson.addData({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
                [-45, -45],
                [-45, 45],
                [45, 45],
                [45, -45],
                [-45, -45]
            ]]
        }
    }]
});
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/d1tLOIEeBPsv7YFDWavA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, see my response at @chrki's answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. It's a shame it this big of a hassle, but it gets the job done. I am going to accept @chrki's answer because he was first, but I did want to thank you again for helping me out with this. Much appreciated.